# The React application does not start

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Faced with such a problem when launching the React app:

Failed to compile.
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.

- configuration.cache.cacheDirectory: The provided value "D:\!_FrontEnd\untitled1\my-app\node_modules\.cache" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
  -> Base directory for the cache (defaults to node_modules/.cache/webpack).
- configuration.module.rules[1].oneOf[3].include: The provided value "D:\!_FrontEnd\untitled1\my-app\src" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
- configuration.output.path: The provided value "D:\!_FrontEnd\untitled1\my-app\build" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
  -> The output directory as **absolute path** (required).

Help, please decide or tell me what I’m doing wrong.

I wanted to launch the React application.

Comment: Post your webpack.config.  Seems that is where the issue is.

Comment: Is one of your directories called `!_FrontEnd`?

Answer (score 3):

As the error says, you need to move your project to a directory whose path does not contain an exclamation mark, because the exclamation mark is [used by Webpack's inline loader selection syntax](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#inline).

Since your project is evidently now in `D:\!_FrontEnd\untitled1\my-app\`, you could rename that to e.g. `D:\_FrontEnd`.